# PDFDocument(data: myPdfDoc.dataRepresentation()) does not reproduce original PDF

Tags: cocoa, quartz-2d, pdfkit

I encounter a weird bug using PDFKit's PDFDocument.

I have an app with a PDFView and the user can drag & drop a PDF on it.
On this event, I save the data representation (NSData) in my core-data structure

```
myCoreDataObject.pdfdata = myPDFView.dataRepresentation()
```

Later, the user can select the core data object to display the PDF, which calls

```
myPDFView.setDocument(PDFDocument(data: myCoreDataObject.pdfdata))
```

The PDF is correctly displayed in the PDFView BUT when the user selects text in it, copy-pastes it in another editor, the selection is made of empty(blank) characters ! Which was not the case with the original dragged-and-dropped PDF.

So my question is: WHY this code:

```
PDFDocument(data: myPdfDoc.dataRepresentation())
```

does not return the exact same PDF ?

IMPORTANT NOTE: this only happens with OCR'd PDF that have been through ABBY FineReader OCR.

Additional information: the "modification" in the PDF only appears when the binary data goes through core data. I ran a test by directly calling

```
PDFDocument(data: PDFDocument(url: myUrl).dataRepresentation())
```

, and the PDF works as expected.

Comment: It's rather easy to check if PDFDocument modifies the data. Just dump data object before and after and compare. There is more chance that this is a PDFView drawing bug rather than data corruption. By the way, you probably meant PDFView.document.dataRepresenation().

Comment: They seem to differ. I also compared 2 binary files generated from the exact same PDF file. Their binary dump differ. `diff file1.bin file2.bin` => Binary files fileA.dump and file2.dump differ. Same result if I transform the files to hex. It looks like the PDFDocument class adds some information to each file dropped to the PDFView.

Comment: macOS 10.15, bug still there :D